# Installing K8s using kOps on local machine

Tags: kubernetes

Has anyone ben able to install Kubernetes using [kOps](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io) on bare metal/ local virtual machine running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of Kops maintainer

> As kOps maintainer, I can at least say that there is no active project to support bare-metal anymore. And the code we once had going in that direction was obsolete and removed.

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/360

If you are looking for installing kubernetes clusters in local bare-metal machine, check out [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/). It is looking very promising.